# Tensorflow: ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've created a keras model with a tensorflow backend but am having difficulty exporting my model for use on ML Engine (as a `saved_model.pb`).  Here's what I'm doing:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data_train, labels_train))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: ({'reviews': x}, y))
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data_test, labels_test))
val_dataset = val_dataset.map(lambda x, y: ({'reviews': x}, y))
dataset = dataset.batch(self.batch_size).repeat()  # repeat infinitely
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(self.batch_size).repeat()
```

Then I perform some preprocessing on my `Dataset` objects:

```
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: preprocess_text_and_y(x,y))
val_dataset = val_dataset.map(lambda x, y: preprocess_text_and_y(x,y))
```

I build my keras model and call `.fit(...)`.  It all works.

Then I try to export my model, with something like this:

```
def export(data_vocab):

    estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(model)

    def serving():
        data_table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(tf.constant(self.data_vocab),
                                                                    default_value=0)
        inputs = {
            'reviews': tf.placeholder(shape=[1], dtype=tf.string)
        }
        preproc = inputs.copy()
        preproc = preprocess_text(preproc, data_table)
        return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(preproc, inputs)

    estimator.export_savedmodel('./test_export', serving)
```

And unfortunately, I get back:

```
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

I googled around and found this:

[How to use TensorFlow Dataset API in combination with dense layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221420/how-to-use-tensorflow-dataset-api-in-combination-with-dense-layers)

which says I need to call `tf.set_shape(...)`.  I'm preprocessing strings into an array of integers with length 100.  I've tried adding `x['reviews'].set_shape([100])` in my `preprocess_text` function

But then that breaks training with:

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1
```

Any thoughts on how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: @rhaertel80 Any ideas would be awesome (if you get the chance)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set the shape after batching, you will need to set it to `[None, 100]` to include the batch axis:

```
x['reviews'].set_shape([None, 100])
```